# How to get last ListView item position using Custom Adapter class?

Tags: android, listview

Hi I am new for android in my app I have created a ListView using Custom Adapter class.

In the ListView footer I have added two buttons like in the image bellowand when I tapped on ADDNEW button, I want to find ListView lost item position.

### ListViewAdapter:-

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Friend> {

    ViewHolder holder;
    private List<Friend> myFriends;
    private Activity activity;

    public ListViewAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<Friend> objects) {

        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
        this.myFriends = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_listview, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.goButton.setTag(position);

        holder.binNumberEditText.setText(getItem(position).getBinNumberEditText());
        holder.qtyEditText.setText(getItem(position).getQtyEditText());
        holder.goButton.setOnClickListener(onConfirmListener());

        return convertView;
    }

     public void adding(String result){

            int position = ListViewadapter.getPosition();

            if (position != null && !position.isEmpty() && !position.equals("null")){

                myFriends.add(new Friend("", ""));
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }else{
                System.out.println("Yes there is null value");
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show your CustomAdapter ?

Comment: yes i edited please see

Comment: Where do you wan't to call `adding` method actually ? I mean what is it's purpose ?

Comment: You can add a funcion in your Adapter like `getLastObject()` and in that your do that : `return myFriend.get(myFriend.size() - 1);`

Comment: int lostposition = myFriends.get(myFriends.size() - 1);

Comment: but showing errors

Comment: What are you willing to get actually ? The position of last item or last object ?

Comment: the position of lost row in listview

Comment: int lostposition = myFriends.get(myFriends.size() - 1);

Comment: when paste this code

Comment: @Krish Why do you want to find the last row? The item you are adding is the last row.

Comment: showing incompactable types when cursor over on it

Comment: @Krish `myFriends.get(myFriends.size() - 1);` will give you the last item. `myFriends.size() - 1` is the last item position.

Comment: int lostposition = myFriends.get(myFriends.size() - 1);

Comment: showing incompactable types when cursor over on it

Comment: I understand you get an error at this line, but what is the error ? Not where.

Comment: is there any type cast problem?

Comment: @ Raphael Teyssandier this is errors like :-showing incompactable types when cursor over on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Friend getLastFriend(){
    return myFriend.get(myFriend.size() - 1);
}
```

Tell me if you do that.

Comment: then how can we get position in the form of int ?

Comment: You need a int or the Object ? If you need `int` just  `return myFriend.size() - 1;`